# my images in static folder are not being displayed

Tags: html, css, django, python-2.7

i have kept {% load staticfiles %} on top my html document
my css and js files are working properly

```
{% load staticfiles %}
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-80">
 <title>Nirmaan@BPHC</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/nirmaan.js" %}">   </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/nirmaan-css.css" %}">

</head>
<body>
   <div class="three"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my css

```
{% load staticfiles %}
.three {
background-image: url("{% static "ignite-cover.jpg" %}");
background-size:cover;
height:100px;
}
```

where main is my app that i created
the image is in main/static/ignite-cover.jpg

this image is not being displayed
help

Comment: try ```background-image: url("{% static 'ignite-cover.jpg' %}");```

Comment: oh i thought that your .three{} style was in your .html template, i believe that you can't use static in your .css files

Comment: you should put the style in your HTML template, django doesn't provide {% static %} for css files, or use the image's relative path.

Comment: This seems a mistake many novice could make, @HassenPy consider post it as an answer for others who ask for this.

Comment: true, i forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the double quotes, they're breaking your url() parameter, use single quotes instead:

```
background-image: url("{% static 'ignite-cover.jpg' %}");
```

Now, there's one thing left to do, you have to pass that line to your .html template, you can't use template tags in your static files, there are some workarounds to this but they all have some drawbacks.

For your case you should be fine using relative paths instead of bulking your .html file with unnecessary styles ([bad for caching](https://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/inline-small-css.html)):

```
background-image: url("your/static/directory/ignite-cover.jpg");
```

Hope this helps!